# Gorm find or save multiple

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have perhaps a issue in the multiple find or save.

Here is the init process

> Typecard typecard = Typecard.findOrSaveByName("personne")
>
> Proposal proposal = Proposal.findOrSaveByName("Proposition 1")
>
> Proposal proposal1 = Proposal.findOrSaveByName("Proposition 2")

First save sequence works perfectly !

> Card card = new Card(typecard: typecard,proposals: [proposal])
>
> card.save()

However the seconde sequence doesn't work :(

> Card.findOrSaveByTypecardAndProposals(typecard,[proposal1])

My question is simple : why ? if you have a idea..

Here this error log,

```
Error |
2014-12-11 23:37:41,586 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Parameter "#3" is not set; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.typecard_id as typecard3_0_0_ from card this_ where this_.typecard_id=? and this_.id=? limit ? [90012-176]

Error |
2014-12-11 23:37:41,600 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [90012]; error code [90012]; Parameter "#3" is not set; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.typecard_id as typecard3_0_0_ from card this_ where this_.typecard_id=? and this_.id=? limit ? [90012-176]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#3" is not set; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.typecard_id as typecard3_0_0_ from card this_ where this_.typecard_id=? and this_.id=? limit ? [90012-176]
Message: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [90012]; error code [90012]; Parameter "#3" is not set; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.typecard_id as typecard3_0_0_ from card this_ where this_.typecard_id=? and this_.id=? limit ? [90012-176]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#3" is not set; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, this_.typecard_id as typecard3_0_0_ from card this_ where this_.typecard_id=? and this_.id=? limit ? [90012-176]
```

I create gist for see log in integrality https://gist.github.com/sovlin/af7f8746d3bc3e752d13

And I create simple app for example https://github.com/sovlin/bugGORM

Comment: That looks like it might be a bug in GORM and/or Hibernate.  If you file a report at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS and attach a simple sample app which demonstrates the problem, we can look into it.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, i make it :) https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11872